# building chrome extension to read selected words from a web page

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I would like to build a chrome extension to allow me select any word from any web page and by clicking a menu item to send it to a service of my company for tracking.

for example, if I am now reading some article on a page, I would like to select a specific word and right click on it, then I would like to make an http request to my service and track this word.

Is it possible to do with chrome extension? can you please link me to a tutorial that can be helpful?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use chrome extension to achieve that.
Refer [Official Tutorial](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions) for more details.
Per your requirements, you may need:

1. Select a specific word. [window.getSelection()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection)
2. right click on it. You will need to listen to mousedown, mouseup or contextmenu event, the code looks like

   ```
   document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(event){...}, false);
   ```
3. make an http request. You can use XMLHttpRequest to transfer data between client and server.